# Container in Bottom Navigation Bar taking whole screen

Tags: flutter

I want to put a container in the bottom navigation bar for my app but it's taking up the whole screen

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: Dimensions.sizeWidthPercent(16),
          right: Dimensions.sizeWidthPercent(16),
          bottom: Dimensions.sizeHeightPercent(30)),
      child: Column(
        children: const [
          TextContainer(text: 'Proceed to request dispatcher')
        ],
      ),
    )
```

[image: This is what happens the whole scaffold body goes missing]

This is what happens the whole scaffold body goes missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was here.Column will expand vertically when no size was not declared to his parent vertically. So you need to declare main axis size for the column. Add following mainAxis Size to the column.

```
 mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,
```

So the full code for above is,

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: Dimensions.sizeWidthPercent(16),
          right: Dimensions.sizeWidthPercent(16),
          bottom: Dimensions.sizeHeightPercent(30)),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,
        children: const [
          TextContainer(text: 'Proceed to request dispatcher')
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add height to the container, it will resolve the issue